# I don't have access to webservice, what to do?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

When I test in the browser it works, but when I call it from another application I don't have access. What to do? The application where the webservice is using windows authentication. It's propably there the problem is, I suppose!

**I solved it:**

*They are on the same domain but not on the same application. I pass
the authentication with the webservice call:*

```
 cm.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging what goes over the wire with something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication for a web service provides some challenges; the web service would need to be on the same domain for that to work I believe, so that it could use the user's credentials.

Do you have to use windows credentials?  Using a ticketing system, which requires the user to first login through another web service method, can work just as well.